# Unable to cast object of type 'ImagesFlag' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ImagesFlag]'

Tags: vb.net, linq, casting, concatenation

And here is the code that produces the error

```
Private Function GetFlag(ByVal ImagesFlagList As IQueryable(Of ImagesFlag)) As String
 ImagesFlagList = ImagesFlagList.AsEnumerable().Concat(New ImagesFlag With _
 {.Flag = "test"}).AsQueryable()
 Return "something"
End Function
```

How can i cast this one?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here

```
.Concat(New ImagesFlag With {.Flag = "test"})
```

`Concat` wants a sequence, an `IEnumerable<ImagesFlag>`, and you are passing it just an `ImagesFlag`. You will need to pass a sequence of flags, it could simply be an an array of that one item.

```
Dim array as ImagesFlag() = { new ImagesFlag With { .Flag = "test" } }
```

And then you can use the array in the call to Concat

```
.Concat(array)
```